# CR removed from csv using mule sftp connector

Tags: mule, integration, sftp, mule-component, mule-esb

I am writing a csv file to the 'Linux sftp' location using mulesoft sftp connector. Unfortunately , when i write csv file to sftp location, 'CR' is being removed from each line of the csv . Client is very much specific with 'CR' and they want it be present in file to be able to successfully process it. I was doing some research on this and found out we should use 'ASCII mode ' or 'text mode' for transmitting data to/ from sftp to preserver 'CR'. I don't find any option to set transfer mode on SFTP connector . Anybody has encountered this issue ? can anybody please help me with this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the encoding as **US ASCII**

Go to your SFTP connector > **Advanced** tab > "Encoding" drop down > Select Encoding **US ASCII**

Let us know if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Yes , I did it.. But its working only in local but its not working when deployed to cloud hub .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201533/issue-writing-file-to-sftp-carriage-return-removed

Comment: @NaveenRayappa , In question asked in this post,you asked about a way to setup ASCII mode in SFTP.The answer given gives you the way..clear..pretty much.And you now created a new question to ask something more on top of this.So Either accept this asnwer so that other looking a way out for this scenario would get that resolved.Or delete other post and update this question.If I get answer may be i will post it on other question opened by you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Mahesh .. what ever you suggested completely works . Actually explicitly setting %output application/csv lineSeparator="\r\n" worked for me to resolve this from CH