# Issue writing file to sftp - carriage return removed

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb, cloudhub

I have a simple requirement where i have to write a csv to linux sftp . In the current implementation Which I have done CR-'carriage return' is being removed when writting the csv to sftp using mulesoft sftp connector . I have set encoding=US-ASCII on the sftp connector , in the dataweave , even in the property file as mule.encoding=US-ASCII.
 Nothing seems like working in cloud hub , but surprisingly the same works fine in my local . 
 I understand after reading few blogs/ white papers that trasfer type should be 'ASCII' when writing to Linux SFTP .
 This is clearly an issue with cloudHub I believe . Any help is much appreciated .

Comment: Explicitly setting %output application/csv lineSeparator="\r\n" worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Add this as an answer and accept it to help future people with the same issue ;) without it your problem remains unsolved for SO

Comment: I did that . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly setting %output application/csv lineSeparator="\r\n" worked for me. Thanks